# Meteor one time or "static" publish without collection tracking

Tags: database, meteor, publish-subscribe

Suppose that one needs to send the same collection of 10,000 documents down to every client for a Meteor app.

At a high level, I'm aware that the server does some bookkeeping for every client subscription - namely, it tracks the state of the subscription so that it can send the appropriate changes for the client. However, this is horribly inefficient if each client has the same large data set where each document has many fields.

It seems that there [used to be a way to send a "static" publish down the wire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871104/586086), where the initial query was published and never changed again. This seems like a much more efficient way to do this.

Is there a correct way to do this in the current version of Meteor (0.6.5.1)?

**EDIT: As a clarification, this question isn't about client-side reactivity. It's about reducing the overhead of server-side tracking of client collections.**

A related question: [Is there a way to tell meteor a collection is static (will never change)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699022/586086)

**Update: It turns out that doing this in Meteor 0.7 or earlier will incur some serious performance issues. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835534/586086 for how we got around this.**

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.meteor.com/#find:

Statics.find({}, {reactive: false} )

Edited to reflect comment:

Do you have some information that the reactive: false param is only client side?  You may be right, it's a reasonable, maybe likely interpretation.  I don't have time to check, but I thought this may also be a server side directive, saying not to poll the mongo result set.  Willing to learn...

You say

```
However, this is horribly inefficient if each client has the same large data set where each document has many fields.
```

Now we are possibly discussing the efficiency of the server code, and its polling of the mongo source for updates that happen outside of from the server.  Please make that another question, which is far above my ability to answer!  I doubt that is happening once per connected client, more likely is a sync between app server info and mongo server.

The client requests you issue, including sorting, should all be labelled non-reactive.  That is separate from whether you can issue them with sorting instructions, or whether they can be retriggered through other reactivity, but which need not include a trip to the server.  Once each document reaches the client side, it is cached.  You can still do whatever minimongo does, no loss in ability.  There is no client asking server if there are updates, you don't need to shut that off.  The server pushes only when needed.

Comment: This is a client-side feature. I'm talking about the subscription tracking on the server side. One may still want reactive cursors on the client side if the collection is sorted by a `Session` variable, for example.

Comment: By the way, I think you added conditions to the question, and then someone downvoted both of my correct answers.  In the face of other people judging those answers helpful.  Probably not in the spirit of this (free) collaboration.

Comment: I downvoted your answers because I think you misunderstood the question and your answers were misleading. See http://docs.meteor.com/#find for the details about reactivity for `find`. It's not true at all that you wouldn't want client-side reactivity with a static subscription. Again, a specific example is if you were changing the sort order client-side. If your cursors were nonreactive, they wouldn't change if you updated a sort parameter.

The issue is not that the server won't push data if it's not needed; it's that the server tracks client-side data unnecessarily.

Comment: Your templates will change if you refire a helper with a different sort order, reactive or not.  Well, sorry this is a pissing match.  1) Reactive != retrieving in a different order. 2) we agree on the ref for find.  You see the word clients only (which are not physically there) because you interpret the word reactive your way.  I interpret it to mean 'monitor changes and republish them.'  If mongo db gets inserts from another app, non reactive in this context could mean don't keep repolling the db server.  We don't need to convince each other.

Comment: No, you're right. I was thinking of a sort specifier depending on a reactive session variable. In any case, `{reactive: false}` is client only (as per the docs) and you can't use it to save work on the server. I don't understand the comment about not having time to check; it is plainly in the docs as I linked. What you're saying about avoiding observing/polling is not possible from what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I finally read that right.  I kept reading the section below with the example.  Sorry!  Learned something again!

Answer (score 1):

I think using the manual publish ( `this.added` ) still works to get rid of overhead created by the server observing data for changes.  The observers either need to be added manually or are created by returning a Collection.curser.

If the data set is big you might also be concerned about the overhead of a [merge box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113256/how-efficient-can-meteor-be-while-sharing-a-huge-collection-among-many-clients/13867122#13867122) holding a copy of the data for each client.  To get rid of that you could copy the collection locally and stop the subscription.

```
var staticData = new Meteor.Collection( "staticData" );

if (Meteor.isServer ){
  var dataToPublish = staticData.find().fetch();  // query mongo when server starts

  Meteor.publish( "publishOnce" , function () {
    var self = this;
    dataToPublish.forEach(function (doc) {
      self.added("staticData", doc._id, doc);  //sends data to client and will not continue to observe collection
    });
  });
}

if ( Meteor.isClient ){
  var subHandle = Meteor.subscribe( "publishOnce" );  // fills client 'staticData' collection but also leave merge box copy of data on server

  var staticDataLocal = new Meteor.Collection( null );  // to store data after subscription stops

  Deps.autorun( function(){
    if ( subHandle.ready() ){
      staticData.find( {} ).forEach( function ( doc ){ 
        staticDataLocal.insert( doc );  // move all data to local copy
      });
      subHandle.stop();  // removes 'publishOnce' data from merge box on server but leaves 'staticData' collection empty on client
    }
  });
}
```

update:  I added comments to the code to make my approach more clear.  The meteor docs for `stop()` on the subscribe handle say "This will typically result in the server directing the client to remove the subscription's data from the client's cache" so maybe there is a way to stop the subscription ( remove from merge box ) that leaves the data on the client.  That would be ideal and avoid the copying overhead on the client.

Anyway the original approach with `set` and `flush` would also have left the data in merge box so maybe that is alright.

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but the subscription handle is not the same as a collection cursor. All of that stuff is going to get inserted into a client-side collection anyway, so the extra copy to another collection is just wasted computation. There should be a more concise way to achieve this with the collection that is synced by the subscription.

Comment: I agree that the subscription handle is not the same as a collection cursor.  I only use the subscription handle to stop the subscription - otherwise all the data will remain in the server's copy of the client data (merge box).  Stopping subscription without losing the subscribed data is ideal but without that the copy is necessary.

Comment: Yep, there are two optimizations here: 1) not incurring the overhead of a mongo observe and 2) not incurring the storage penalty of the merge box/client cache/whatever on the server. Your answer gives the best solution to 1) but 2) still seems up in the air at this point.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already pointed out yourself in googlegroups, you should use a Meteor Method for sending static data to the client.
And there is [this neat package](https://atmospherejs.com/msavin/fetcher) for working with Methods without async headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could script out the data to a js file, as either an array or an object, minimize it, then link to it as a distinct resource.    See 
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html for Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header.  You probably don't want meteor to bundle it for you.

This would be the least traffic, and could make subsequent loads of your site much swifter.

Comment: Wouldn't this completely miss the point of making the data available in a client-side collection?

Answer (score 0):

as a response to a Meteor call, return an array of documents (use fetch())  No reactivity or logging.  On client, create a dep when you do a query, or retrieve the key from the session, and it is reactive on the client.

Mini mongo just does js array/object manipulation with an syntax interpreting dsl between you and your data.

Answer (score -1):

The new [fast-render package](http://meteorhacks.com/fast-render/api/) makes one time publish to a client collection possible.

```
var staticData = new Meteor.Collection ('staticData');

if ( Meteor.isServer ){

  FastRender.onAllRoutes( function(){
    this.find( staticData, {} );
  });
}
```